# Laravel 4.2 custom code on end of script

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add some custom code on laravel 4.2 framework when the script is finish executed. 
I havd try to add the code at end of public/index.php but it seem doesnt work.

Can you advise where should I put the script on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `app/filters.php` and find this:

```
App::after(function($request, $response) {
    // your code goes here
});
```